# Verilog Instantiating module inside a always block. Using Adder for multiplication

Tags: module, verilog, instantiation, modelsim

I have a code written for multiplying two 53 bit numbers (written below). I am using shift-add strategy using two other 106 bit registers. This code is working fine. Now I have another 53 bit highly optimized hans carlson adder module written in form:

module hans_carlson_adder(input [52:0] a, b, input c_in, output [52:0] sum, output c_out);

I want to use this adder to do the summation line in for loop (mentioned in code). I am having problem instantiating the adder inside an always block. Plus I dont want to have 106 instances (due to for loop) of this adder. Can you please help with this code

```
  module mul1(
                output reg [105:0]  c,
                input [52:0]   x,
                input [52:0]   y,
            input clk,
            input state
            ); 

        reg [105:0] p;
        reg [105:0]a;
        integer i;

        always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (state==1) begin

          a={53'b0,x[52:0]};
          p=106'b0; // needs to zeroed
          for(i=0;i<106;i=i+1) begin
            if(y[i]) begin
              p=p+a; //THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE REPLACED WITH HANS CARLSONADDER
            end
            a=a<<1;
          end

        c<=p;

        end else begin
         c=0;

        end
        end
        endmodule
```

Comment: You have two choices: 1) 52 adders that do the multiplication in one cycle 2) one adder that does the multiplication in 52 cycles. Which do you want to do. Note: Your original code didn't need to loop 106 times since there aren't that many bits in y. You can't instantiate a module in an always block, so either create the instances outside the always, or get a function implementation instead.

Comment: @Brad Budlong I want one adder implementation in 52 cycles. (Since the operands would be 106 bit so I would have to use two). I dont understand how I can instantiate the module outside and still use the function like I am doing the addition in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to instantiate your adder outside of the always block and connect it to signals:

```
wire [52:0] b;
reg [5:0] count;
assign b = c[count+7'd52:count];
wire [52:0] sum;
wire c_out;
// Add in x depending on the bits in y
// b has the running result bits that still apply at this point
hans_carlson_adder u0(x, b, 1'b0, sum, c_out);
```

Now because this is a pipelined adder you are going to need something to kick off the multiplication (I'll call that `input start`) and something that indicates that the result is available (I'll call that `output reg done`).  You'll want to add them to your `mul1` module definition. You can choose a slightly different protocol depending on your needs. It appears that you have something that you've been implementing with the `input state`. I'm also going to use `start` to initialize during each calculation so that I don't need a separate reset signal.

```
reg [52:0] shift;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (start) begin
    done <= 0;
    count <= 0;
    c <= 106'b0;
    shift <= y;
  end else if (count < 53) begin
    if (shift[0]) begin
      c[count+7'd52:count] <= sum;
      c[count+7'd53] <= c_out;
    end
    count <= count + 1;
    shift = shift >> 1;
  end else begin
    done <= 1;
  end
end
```

If you want to make an optimization you could end once the `shift` signal is equal to 0.  In this case the `done` signal would become high as soon as there were no more bits to add into the result, so multiplying by small values of `y` would take less cycles.

Comment: `c[count+7'd52:count]` will not complete. Maybe you meant `c[count +: 53]`